# Localized Storyboards with Base.lproj

Tags: ios, localization, storyboard, ios6

What's the best way to update my localized storyboard's .strings files when working with iOS 6 and the new localization? My project created the strings files nicely when I switched to the new Base.lproj mechanism, but it does not update the .strings files on the fly.

Thanks!
–f

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the script below to "Build Phases"->"Run Script"

[image]

```
#!/bin/sh
# cls.sh - script to  Create Locale Strings auto

storyboardExt=".storyboard"
stringsExt=".strings"
newStringsExt=".strings.new"
oldStringsExt=".strings.old"
localeDirExt=".lproj"

# Find storyboard file full path inside project folder
for storyboardPath in `find ${SRCROOT} -name "*$storyboardExt" -print`
do
    # Get Base strings file full path
    baseStringsPath=$(echo "$storyboardPath" | sed "s/$storyboardExt/$stringsExt/")

    # Create strings file only when storyboard file newer
    if find $storyboardPath -prune -newer $baseStringsPath -print | grep -q .; then
        # Get storyboard file name and folder 
        storyboardFile=$(basename "$storyboardPath")
        storyboardDir=$(dirname "$storyboardPath")

        # Get New Base strings file full path and strings file name
        newBaseStringsPath=$(echo "$storyboardPath" | sed "s/$storyboardExt/$newStringsExt/")
        stringsFile=$(basename "$baseStringsPath")
        ibtool --export-strings-file $newBaseStringsPath $storyboardPath
        iconv -f UTF-16 -t UTF-8 $newBaseStringsPath > $baseStringsPath
        rm $newBaseStringsPath

        # Get all locale strings folder 
        for localeStringsDir in `find ${SRCROOT} -name "*$localeDirExt" -print`
        do
            # Skip Base strings folder
            if [ $localeStringsDir != $storyboardDir ]; then
                localeStringsPath=$localeStringsDir/$stringsFile

                # Just copy base strings file on first time
                if [ ! -e $localeStringsPath ]; then
                    cp $baseStringsPath $localeStringsPath
                else
                    oldLocaleStringsPath=$(echo "$localeStringsPath" | sed "s/$stringsExt/$oldStringsExt/")
                    cp $localeStringsPath $oldLocaleStringsPath

                    # Merge baseStringsPath to localeStringsPath
                    awk 'NR == FNR && /^\/\*/ {x=$0; getline; a[x]=$0; next} /^\/\*/ {x=$0; print; getline; $0=a[x]?a[x]:$0; printf $0"\n\n"}' $oldLocaleStringsPath $baseStringsPath > $localeStringsPath

                    rm $oldLocaleStringsPath
                fi
            fi
        done
    else
        echo "$storyboardPath file not modified."
    fi
done
```

Comment: From [http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1467446](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1467446)

Comment: Thanks! This one seems to have issues with paths that contain spaces. I keep getting "no file or directory" errors when running that script from the build phase and the outputs indicates that it broke on the space between "Macintosh" and "HD".

Comment: Just put quote(") to the broke path in cls.sh, like "${SRCROOT}"

Answer (score 9):

From Apple's "Internationalization and Localization Guide", at the bottom of it all:

Inside the Base.lproj directory of your project type

```
ibtool MainStoryboard.storyboard --generate-strings-file NewStuff.strings
```

Then merge from `NewStuff.strings` to your `Storyboard.strings` files and translate.

EDITED LINK: 
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/MaintaingYourOwnStringsFiles/MaintaingYourOwnStringsFiles.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000171i-CH19-SW22

Comment: that link points to a document that has been retired. Not easy to see where the relevant information is now.